# Scala two list match data

Tags: scala, scala-collections

First List data as below

```
List(("A",66729122803169854198650092,"SD"),("B",14941578978240528153321786,"HD"),("C",14941578978240528153321786,"PD"))
```

and second list contains data as below

```
List(("X",14941578978240528153321786),("Y",68277588597782900503675727),("Z",14941578978240528153321786),("L"66729122803169854198650092))
```

using above two list I want to form following list which matched first list second number to second list second number so my output should as below

```
List(("X",14941578978240528153321786,"B","HD"),("X",14941578978240528153321786,"C","PD"),   ("Y",68277588597782900503675727,"",""),("Z",14941578978240528153321786,"B","HD"),("Z",14941578978240528153321786,"C","PD"),
("L",66729122803169854198650092,"A","SD"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val tuples3 = List(
  ("A", "66729122803169854198650092", "SD"),
  ("B", "14941578978240528153321786", "HD"),
  ("C", "14941578978240528153321786", "PD"))

val tuples2 = List(
  ("X", "14941578978240528153321786"),
  ("Y", "68277588597782900503675727"),
  ("Z", "14941578978240528153321786"),
  ("L", "66729122803169854198650092"))
```

Group first list by target field:

```
val tuples3Grouped =
  tuples3
    .groupBy(_._2)
    .mapValues(_.map(t => (t._1, t._3)))
    .withDefaultValue(List(("", "")))
```

Zip all data:

```
val result = for{ (first, second) <- tuples2
     t <- tuples3Grouped(second)
} yield (first, second, t._1, t._2)
```

Comment: If above tuples3 like this  ("A", "66729122803169854198650092", "SD","P","Q","R","S") then how this tuples3 match with tuples2?

Comment: @yogesh if you want genelarize input data solution would be more complicated